# How to use switch on the value with an Option?

Tags: functional-programming, language-ext

I am using LanguageExt but I suspect the same question applies to other FP languages. I got myself in the situation below and would love to have some advice:

- Check the value in an Option
- Depending on the value, a different function is applied
- The problem is that the functions return different types

How do I make this work? I am having a hard time getting the value out of the monad and apply the functions.

Comment: Please give us a more concrete example.

Comment: _"The problem is that the functions return different types"_ - **that's not a problem**, it just means you need to use a union-type (or a type-union... I forget) to represent the return value.

Comment: ...and LanguageExt [has loads of neat features for handling and generating unions and other types](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext#code-generation).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dai, I will check out the union type. If that does not work out I will add more an example to the question.

Comment: The phrase *"getting the value out of the monad"* is frequently an indication that you're trying to do something you shouldn't:  https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/04/how-to-get-the-value-out-of-the-monad